# Fixed div bottom panel when height increase

Tags: javascript, css

Please have a look at the following code

https://jsfiddle.net/kamrant/qku5cp1w/1/

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    height: 100%
}

#panel {
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The bottom panel acts fine (stays at the bottom of its container) however I have a tree view inside the container and when the tree is expanded as a result the container height increases, when scroll, my bottom panel stay where it is and does not adjust its position to the bottom of the container.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Are u trying to make the `#panel` position fixed to the container even when the container is scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#main {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
}

#container {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
   width: 400px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 600px;
   padding: 0 0 35px 0;
}

#panel {
   height: 35px;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   background: #EEEEEE;
   bottom: 1px;
   left: 1px;
}

#otherstuff {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">

  <div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed fermentum ligula id neque laoreet lobortis. Nam laoreet ligula nec sapien finibus, interdum efficitur odio sollicitudin. Vivamus vitae erat nibh. Curabitur non magna quis sapien elementum porttitor vel et nulla. Nunc ultricies nisi quis eros ullamcorper, vitae malesuada velit venenatis. Suspendisse ultricies justo non ipsum pellentesque, eu consectetur massa ultricies. Morbi vel euismod erat, in condimentum elit. Aenean blandit mi ut nulla convallis, nec pellentesque mi facilisis. Sed vitae viverra mi, eu dapibus magna. Sed sollicitudin, velit sit amet tristique placerat, ante massa semper mi, id ultrices elit libero sit amet velit. Vivamus vitae lorem pretium nulla iaculis aliquet. Duis elementum erat vel pretium viverra. Phasellus ac ante quis tortor sollicitudin tristique. Ut tellus sem, congue sed arcu nec, venenatis efficitur risus. Curabitur ullamcorper viverra sapien ut maximus. Quisque ac elit finibus, fringilla diam ac, fermentum sapien.<br /><br />

Donec mattis sapien quis risus dictum aliquet. Etiam tristique tristique ex ut pharetra. Nulla vehicula tempor mauris ac ullamcorper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam erat volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed eu varius dui. Curabitur ornare nibh hendrerit eros lacinia semper. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean turpis dolor, posuere sit amet sapien quis, luctus viverra leo. Vivamus auctor, lorem et tempus fermentum, lorem velit ultrices nisi, ac bibendum felis ante vel erat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent imperdiet vitae mauris nec fermentum. asd
    </div>
    <div id="panel">do stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div id="otherstuff"></div>

</div>
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the height of the container to 600px (I changed it to 100 for easier viewing on jsfiddle) which restricts the growth. Would be better use to use min-height, allowing div height to grow as content grows.

I suggest putting content inside its own div, so I made a new div ("tree") to contain the tree view you were talking about. This allows you to target just the content of this div in the future, should it come to that.

When you have an absolute position, it will take up the the space the inside which the div it belongs to, hence the extra padding inside the .tree css to allow for that content to not overlap the "tree" div.

```
#container {
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

See jsfiddle for the full code https://jsfiddle.net/jennift/qku5cp1w/4/